# Doesn't Mongo use indexes after { $match: { $text: { $search: search } }?

Tags: mongodb

I have pipeline:

```
[ { '$match': { '$text': [Object] } },
{ '$addFields': { sortFieldTextRelevance: [Object] } },
{ '$match': { '$and': [Array] } } ]
```

And I see that indexes for second match are not being used, but if I remove

```
 { $match: { $text: { $search: search } }
```

everything is fine. What may be wrong?

Comment: This is what happens https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-operators-and-performance reads:

> The $match and $sort pipeline operators can take advantage of an index when they occur at the **beginning** of the pipeline.

So indexes are intended to work only on the first stage match.

If you can create a [compound text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#compound-index) you can use it by combining both matches into first stage:

```
[ { '$match': { '$and': [...Array, { '$text': [Object] }] }  },
{ '$addFields': { sortFieldTextRelevance: [Object] } }]
```

Comment: It has changed : `Changed in version 3.2: Starting in MongoDB 3.2, indexes can cover an aggregation pipeline. In MongoDB 2.6 and 3.0, indexes could not cover an aggregation pipeline since even when the pipeline uses an index, aggregation still requires access to the actual documents.`

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti, that's true but the question is not about covered indexes. In any case covered or not indexes work only on the first stage.

Comment: but according to official documentation, they say that indexes can cover entire aggregation pipeline

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti no, I guess you confuse meaning of "cover" here. In the quote it's being used in context of [covered query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query) - in some cases mongo can use index alone without reading whole documents. It didn't work for aggregation until v3.2. Previous versions of the db fetched whole documents even when conditions of the first stage match were suitable for covered queries. See details in https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5090. They never said "entire pipeline".

Comment: @AlexBlex thx, but I can't create compound index in my situation, i need use two different indexes for each match.